# How to stop nil values in a list being counted

Tags: list, lua, null, counting

I have a function which is returning `"Match"` if true and `nil` else. I need to know the number of values in the list which `"Match"` (hence using `nil` as the other value in my function).

```
someList = {"gdj", nil, "jdis"}

print(#someList) --> 3
```

My origination question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56873993/if-x-amount-of-these-facts-are-true-then-return-y-in-lua) if there is something I should be returning other than nil!

Comment: Unrelated to the problem: Why not simply return *true* if true and *false* else?

Comment: There is no problem returning true and false, I was actually converting someone else's code from a DSL into Lua and just kept the conventions.

Comment: Related question: [Why does Lua's length (#) operator return unexpected values? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23590885/why-does-luas-length-operator-return-unexpected-values?noredirect=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#` operator is defined in a rather weird way; it will count until *one of* non-nil elements. In your case, it's entirely possible that it could return `1` as well. This is because [Lua doesn't really support storing nils in tables](http://lua-users.org/wiki/StoringNilsInTables).

As such, there's no definite way to iterate over such a table, unless you know the size of it and can stop the iteration yourself.

It would be much better to store a dedicated "falsy" value, and then simply iterate and count manually using `ipairs`.

Comment: Thanks for your insight Bartek, good to know. Would you mind pointing me in the right direction with implementing that? I'm very new to Lua and very bad with tables!

Comment: @Bee In your original question, simply change `return nil` to `return "NoMatch"` or something like that. You just need a non-nil value. You could e.g. define it at the start of your program like `my_nil = { }`, and then by using this you'll only store the reference to that empty table.

Comment: Hi Bartek, thanks again, I do understand that bit, I'm not entirely sure how to use ipairs! Either way, you answered my initial question

Comment: @Bee I learned about `ipairs` from the excellent Lua [Reference Manual](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-ipairs).

Comment: @Tom, obviously I have read the full manual and tried using that to create this but was obviously still having issues, hence asking. I have found help elsewhere